# iOS KVO observe another class property

Tags: ios, observers

Is there anyway observe another class propery, like observe an singleton instance in iOS. I have tried, but I don't know hot to write keypath from another class.

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"otherclass/keypath" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver of the `addObserver` message is the observed object. So it should be the instance of your singleton. The keypath should start with the name of a observable property of this singleton. E.g.:

```
[[SingletonClass instance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"propertyName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

A keypath can contain a chain of property names which are separated by dots. Just for illustration: If you want observe the root view controller of the key window, you can do

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] addObserver:self 
    forKeyPath:@"keyWindow.rootViewController" 
    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
[Otherclass addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"keypath" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```